# Как метод класса может получить переменную из функции?

Tags: javascript

```js
function makeClass(phrase) {
  return class {
    sayHi() {
      alert(phrase);
    };
  };
}

let User = makeClass("Привет");

new User().sayHi();
```

1. В переменную **User**  возвращается **class** из функции **makeClass**
2. **new User()** создается пустой объект в его прототипе находится метод **sayHi**
3. Вызываем метод **sayHi** т.к объект пустой метод найдется в прототипе
4. Вопрос как **alert** получает переменную **phrase** ?
5. Из-за того что **alert** встроенная функция и она может искать переменные во внешнем коде (замыкание) ?

Comment: @Igor призываю!!! пожалуйста ...

Comment: никто не хочет объяснить ... пойду плакать ...

Comment: вы угадали про замыкание, но `alert` тут не причем, Сама `sayHi` возвращаясь вместе с классом, запоминает контекст создания, где есть переменная `phrase`

Comment: @ThisMan `sayHi ` ведь метод разве они могут запоминать место своего создания как функция ?

Comment: да метод, но метод это что? Правильно, функция

Comment: ThisMan я правильно понял что `sayHi ` нет  this тогда это функция ?

Comment: `this` есть всегда, но чему он равен, зависит от способа вызова

Comment: @ThisMan у метода `sayHi ` нет this; я походу что-то не догоняю ...

Comment: почитайте про `this` вы очень базовые вопросы задаете

Comment: ThisMan я в курсе что когда вызывается метод и в нем прописан this он равен объекту перед точкой; у метода sayHi  нет this ...

Comment: __this есть всегда, но чему он равен, зависит от способа вызова__

Comment: @ThisMan получается this есть у sayHi  только не указан явно ?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98835/discussion-between-thisman-and-user349791).